# Inserting many entities one by one

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to insert many rows but one by one - not in a bulk:

```
    var setOrder = 0        
       for (exercise in exercisedWithSetsDTO) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                var training = TrainingExercise(
                    trainingId,
                    exercise.id,
                    exercise.setNo
                )

                var trainingId = trainingDao.insert(training)

                for (i in 1..training.setsNumber) {
                    setDao.insert(SetEntity(trainingId.toInt(), setOrder))
                    setOrder++
                }
            }
        }
```

"var trainingId = trainingDao.insert(training)" - until that moment it works. All trainings are added.

Problem is that

```
             for (i in 1..training.setsNumber) {
                    setDao.insert(SetEntity(trainingId.toInt(), setOrder))
                    setOrder++
                }
```

is not working. Nothing is inserted to db.

I assume that problem is because I try to do "setDao.insert(SetEntity(trainingId.toInt(), setOrder))" before "var trainingId = trainingDao.insert(training)" is finished but I am not sure and don't know how to solve it.

Previously I had a problem with adding trainings but when I moved viewModelScope.launch inside "for" at least adding trainings works - I am not sure if that is correct approach or I only "hacked" my problem

Comment: I managed to fix that. Answer is simple but not sure if I should do that way even if it is working. I moved "viewModelScope.launch {" outside of first loop and added "runBlocking"

Answer (score 1):

Try using async-await like following

```
        viewModelScope.launch {
        var training = TrainingExercise(
            trainingId,
            exercise.id,
            exercise.setNo
        )

        var tId = async { trainingDao.insert(training) }
        val trainingId  = tId.await()
        for (i in 1..training.setsNumber) {
            setDao.insert(SetEntity(trainingId.toInt(), setOrder))
            setOrder++
        }
    }
```

`async` will return a Deferred value to which `.await()` will wait until async complete